# Reddit API Authentication Issue (OAuth)

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, reddit, rest

The following code throws a 401 error and the access_token does not get retrieved. It seems like https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token is rejecting the username/password or clientID/Secretkey that I have provided. But all that info is correct, the username and password is absolutely same as the Reddit login details, and the client ID & Secret key are directly a copy-paste from a dev app created here: https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps

Please suggest what could be wrong

```py
import requests

auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('<client_id>', '<client_secret>')
data = {'grant_type': 'password','username': 'username','password': 'password'}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'ApiTest/0.0.1'}

res = requests.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',auth=auth, data=data, headers=headers)

if "Unauthorized" in res.text:
    print('401 error occured')

TOKEN = res.json()['access_token']

headers = {**headers, **{'Authorization': f"bearer {TOKEN}"}}

requests.get('https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me', headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from `bearer` to `Bearer` in your headers. You can also remove the `**`.
Should be something like this:

```
headers = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {TOKEN}"}
```

Comment: The error is happening at the "requests.post" stage. It is not fetching the appropriate response, res being fetched here is: '{"message": "Unauthorized", "error": 401}'

Comment: have you tried to do `json=data` instead of `data=data` ?

Comment: @dharmey it did not help. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. For me the steps above did not work (they are taken from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-the-reddit-api-in-python-5e05ddfd1e5c)). What I needed to do is to follow the steps in the official documentation [here](https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2#authorization).

1. I included the client ID from the created app, changed the response type to code, and added a random string, i.e. abcr1234 and the redirected uri must be the same as the one in the created app (I used my twitter profile). I

   https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=TYPE&
   state=RANDOM_STRING&redirect_uri=URI&duration=DURATION&scope=SCOPE_STRING
2. I opened the link in my browser which redirected me to my twitter profile and at the of it the code value was generated: ?`state=abcr1234&code=dhHjUGFxMmKMiEcqmdHtxjvKdw#_`
3. I had to remove the last two symbols '#_' (seen in another
   stackoverflow question)
4. Then following the steps from the article, I requested the access
   token, but instead of using the username/password I passed the code
   and the redirect_uri in the post request `https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token/`
   [image]